# Understanding getSystemResource() in Java

Tags: java, javafx

How can I access the icon.png file without specifing the whole path "main/res/images/icon.png" in **ClassLoader.getSystemResource()**? I wanted something like images/icon.png.
[This is the project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAEHP.png)
Main.java:

```
package main.java.OOP20.alt.sim.View;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static final double PROPORTION = 1.5;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Dimension dimension = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        final double width = dimension.getWidth() / PROPORTION;
        final double height = dimension.getHeight() / PROPORTION;

        final Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(
            ClassLoader.getSystemResource("main/res/layouts/sample.fxml")
        );
        primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, width, height));
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(
            new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("main/res/images/icon.png").toString())
        );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want getSystemResource() and not getResource
()?

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get url of both fxml or png files with using `Class<T>#getResource()`. You should use following solutions:

For fxml file:

```java
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/layouts/sample.fxml"));
```

For png file:

```java
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/icon.png").toString()));
```

**Note:** If you want to load any external resources (fxml, png etc) from resource folder within static methods, you must use `Main.class.getClass()` instead of `getClass()`. It guarantees the resource will be loaded relative to that class, and never relative to a subclass.

Comment: This is mostly correct, but getClass() should be replaced with `Main.class`.

Comment: @VGR `getClass()` = `this.getClass()` so in `public void start(final Stage primaryStage)` method, you can call `Main` class with `getClass()`.

Comment: I didn’t say `this.getClass()`.  I said `Main.class`, which is something different.

Comment: @VGR yes `Main.class` is different from `this.getClass() or getClass()`. However for @mitra02 problem, he doesn't need to use `static (Main.class)` if not used within the static metod. `start` method is not static.

Comment: If all that mattered were whether the program compiles, I might agree.  However, using `Main.class` guarantees the resource will be loaded relative to that class, and never relative to a subclass.  It’s good practice to use a class literal when calling getResource or getResourceAsStream.

Comment: @VGR This can be a good practice. I will get this note for my answer. Thank you for clarifying.